# Skip validation when creating has_many :through records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, nested-forms

In my db there are a lot of users with invalid data (without mobile number). Because I added mobile presence validation just now. When I'm trying to add new event, I get error messages "Users mobile number must be in ... format". How I can skip user validation when creating events?

**event.rb**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :users, :through => :participations
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :events, :through => :participations
end
```

**events_controller.rb**

```
 def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to events_path, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
      end
    end
  end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
 <%= form_for @event, :html => {:class => 'row'} do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_messages %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :user_ids, "Participants" %>
      <%= f.collection_select :user_ids, User.all, :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => true } %>

      <%= clear %>

      <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set `validate: false` in Event `has_many :users` association

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :users, :through => :participations, validate: false
end
```

Comment: I'd love to know how to get this working in Rails 5.0.0.RC1.

Comment: Thanks. There is strange behavior when you create parent record and assign child ids like `Event.create(user_ids: [1, 2, 3])` Rails runs `valid?` on each user without assign of `event_id`. So you can't detect if `event_id` changed and skip validation :(.

Comment: Thanks a lot, This answer is very very helpful for me.